# Memory error, html/template in Go

Tags: go

I get some memory error when trying to execute this code:

```
package web

import (
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
)

type Hello struct {
    Level string
}

func Main(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    h := Hello{Level: "gsdfg"}

    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("web.html")
    t.Execute(w, h)
}
```

The error message I get in the browser is this:

```
the runtime process gave a bad HTTP response: ''

2015/03/26 11:34:56 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:43269: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

I dont understand what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[template.ParseFiles](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#ParseFiles) returns an error

```
func ParseFiles(filenames ...string) (*Template, error)
```

> If an error occurs, parsing stops and the returned `*Template` is nil.

You should check the error in case there is an issue.
That could explain why '`t`' might be nil.

In general, the best practice is to never ignore error.

Here:

```
var t *Template
if t, err := template.ParseFiles("web.html"); err != nil {
    // do something
    // return err
    // or
    // panic(err)
}
```

Comment: I guess that there is something wrong with the path to the html template then. The file is in the same dir as my .go file, doesn't a relative path work then?

Comment: @theva the file might be there, but the parsing might be faulty: only by actually *checking* the error will you know for sure.

Comment: So adding log.Fatal(err) i get this:
"2015/03/26 12:04:23 open web.html: no such file or directory", how should I format the path?

Comment: @theva it is case sensitive: do you respect the case for the file name?

Comment: @theva are you executing your program in the same folder as the file is currently?

Comment: No I do not, it is executed form server.go which is in the root of the dir, should the path be relative to that one?

Comment: @theva yes, can you try with a relative path to the server?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use `template.Must` function to cause a panic in case of error. Its usage is justified in this case because the program needs its resources.

```
t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("web.html"))
```

Comment: Good practice indeed. I missed the '`Must()`' method. +1

Comment: Further, the parsing of the template file should likely be moved out of the specific handler unless you really want to re-parse the (likely) unchanged template file for each and every request. (If you want to be able to change the template without restarting the server a better solution would be to reload the server's config on SIGHUP or somesuch).